# ASP.NET Core API authentication using Firebase and Identity

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API that will use Firebase jwt token authentication.

In `Startup.cs` I registered `Identity`:

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => {

            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;

        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And added Jwt Token middleware:

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            IncludeErrorDetails = true,
            Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/[my-project-id]",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/[my-project-id]",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "[my-project-id]",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            },
        });
```

I'm protecting my routes with `[Authorize]` and everything it's working fine. The `HttpContext.User.Identity.Authenticated` property is set to `true`, but everything else on the `User` object is null, name, e-mail, etc.

Is there any way to link the user generated by the token middleware to the users in my database? What's the best approach to access this information from my controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue and was able to get the user email from "HttpContext.User.Claims"

Make sure you generate the POCO classes based on the Json string.

------------------ Controller code ---------------------

```
    [HttpGet("GetAll")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User;
        var claims = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity).Claims;
        var items = claims.ToList();
        var jsonstr = items.Last().Value;

        FirebaseIdentity fb = (FirebaseIdentity)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr, typeof(FirebaseIdentity));
        //**** get the user email address here ***
        var useremail = fb.identities.email[0];

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

------------------ Model classes ---------------------

```
[Serializable, JsonObject]
public class FirebaseIdentity
{
    [JsonProperty("identities")]
    public Identities identities { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sign_in_provider")]
    public string sign_in_provider { get; set; }
}

[Serializable, JsonObject]
public class Identities
{
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public List<string> email { get; set; }
}
```